# c# - calculating decimal numbers from textboxes

Tags: c#, decimal, multiplication

I am having trouble calculating two decimal numbers.

Basically, I am trying to multilpy ounces with grams. I have got two textboxes and the first one should contain ounces (for example **3,5**), while the second one should shown the same value but in grams. So, ounces should be multiplied with **31.1034768** and the result should be shown in the second textbox.

I have been trying to calculate these two in many different ways but none of them actually worked. Here is my last unsuccessful try:

```
private void btn_Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal oz = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_WeightOz.Text);
        decimal ozingrams = 31.1034768M;
        decimal result = Decimal.Multiply(oz, ozingrams);
        txt_WeightGrams.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(result);
    }
```

It says that I cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'string'.

How can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert result to string, as such;

```
txt_WeightGrams.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have already tried that but had no success, since I forgot to add brackets. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't need to convert `decimal` to `decimal`, secondly `Text` is a `string` property, so you need to turn `result` into a `string`, so replace:

```
txt_WeightGrams.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(result);
```

with this:

```
txt_WeightGrams.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: Excuse me, what line are you talking about when you say you shouldn't convert decimal to decimal and what it should look like? When it comes to the result.ToString(), the issue has been solved. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Basicaly `result` is already a `decimal` so you don't need to do `Convert.ToDecimal(result)`

Answer (score 1):

> It says that I cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'string'.

Yes you will get that as you need to convert **result** to **string** like this:

```
txt_WeightGrams.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: I have already tried that but had no success, because I forgot to add brackets. Now it works fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A text box can display only 'string' so you need to convert it before showing in textbox.
DO this

```
txt_WeightGrams.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

or

```
txt_WeightGrams.Text = result.ToString();
```

instead of

```
txt_WeightGrams.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(result);
```